# To achieve ECTS credits at my school a student is forced to drop his/her right of privacy

Tags: privacy, gdpr, academia, netherlands

Some background about the situation:
I attend a vocational university (university of applied sciences)
I live in the Netherlands - Europe

We have a mandatory activity that provides us with ECTS credits (if you don't know: these are required to finish the study in a whole)

The problem I'm facing is that this activity takes place in a commercial enviroment, we have to take part on a day on which al sorts of demo's are being given. The event (which is not an academic one, but purely commercial) is being held at the company, and for taking part one must agree to let the company use personal information (Pictures taken on the day itself for the most part) for commercial endpoints.

I would not like to give this personal information, thus I am not able to attend the event, thus I am not able to get all the required ECTS credits to complete my study. This activity was not described when I started the study but only 1 to 2 months before taking place (in the 2nd year)

My question is: Is there a law that makes this illegal for a university to do? I was thinking maybe the very essential thing a university should be responsible for is neutral education, without making a student giving up his/her privacy for it (not more then essential information at least)

Comment: [Art. 13(1)(c,d)](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-13-gdpr/) requires the company to explain the legal basis of the processing. You should have gotten that information, otherwise you can ask for it. If they base it on [consent](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-7-gdpr/), explain them that consent if invalid if it is not freely given. Alternatively, you can also withdraw your consent during of immediately after the event.

Comment: @wimh You should post that as an answer.